# SSE instruction to interleave top 16-bits of packed 32-bit blocks of two XMM registers?

Tags: x86-64, simd, sse

I can't seem to find any SSE instruction that does exactly this

```
r[15:0]    = a[31:16]  
r[31:16]   = a[63:48]  
r[47:32]   = a[95:80]  
r[63:48]   = a[127:112]  
r[79:64]   = b[31:16]  
r[95:80]   = b[63:48]  
r[111:96]  = b[95:80]  
r[127:112] = b[127:112]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Looked through this https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html
but it's kind of hard to find exactly what you're looking for, so I may have missed something obvious.

Comment: You might need `psrld a, 16` / `psrld b, 16` / `packsswd a, b`; I think that's the operation you're doing.  I don't know if there's anything better.  If those source vectors came from memory, unaligned loads would still require masking instead of shifting since 2-input pack instructions always saturate, not truncate.  AVX-512BW could do this with one `vpermt2w` but that's 3 uops on Intel, unfortunately even on Ice Lake / Alder Lake.  1 uop on Zen 4, though, with 2/clock throughput.

Comment: shift/`pblendw` can get all the data into one register in 2 instructions, but not the order you want so it would need a `pshufb`.

Comment: Maybe you can change how `a` and `b` are generated, to get your desired result with fewer uops?

Comment: @chtz I'm advancing a 32-bit LCRNG in those registers (with `pmulld` and `paddd`) and then I need to retrieve the high 16 bits of each 32-bit state to XOR with some data for encryption, that's why I need them packed sequentially in my final register.

Comment: Can you somehow use `pmulhuw` instead? Also, don't use LCRNGs for "encryption", not even as a toy project ...

Comment: @chtz no I can't use `pmulhuw` because that's not a 32-bit multiplication operation. Also I'm replicating the behavior of another (quite old) program, this wasn't my idea for the encryption part.